# How do i add a hyperlink to a data-image line of code? CSS3

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

I'm doing some work and still fairly new to CSS,

I have some code here,

```
<div id='ninja-slider'>
                <ul>
                   <li>
                       <div data-image="images/md/1.jpg" </div>                   </li>
                  <li>
                       <div data-image="images/md/2.jpg"> </div>
                   </li>
                   <li>
                       <div data-image="images/md/3.jpg"></div>
                   </li>
                   <li>
                       <div data-image="images/md/4.jpg"></div>
                   </li>
               </ul>
           </div>
```

I want to know how can i add a hyperlink to each of these images? I've tried  however it hasn't worked for me unfortunately.

Please help, I even tried Javascript from a  google search. Something to do with onclick

Cheers

Comment: you can add like this `<a href="yourlink";" class="yourclass" runat="server">Update</a>` Or show us some code to help you better

Comment: <a href="#><img src=""></a>

Comment: to be clear: you can't add such a behavior with CSS alone.

Answer (score 0):

wrap the div in `<a>` tag

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><div data-image="images/md/1.jpg"></div></a> 
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `<a></a>` tag.

you can do this

```
<a href="link_page"><img src="your_image.jpg" width="" height=""></a>
```

`href` will contain the page or wherever you want user to redirect.

This approach is better and more widely used than the one's you showed